# How to make a BGUI widget always focused/active?

Tags: python, game-engine

I am trying to make a textual interface that doesn't rely on the mouse in order to focus widgets. All I have is a TextInput widget and I want this to always be focused/active such that it doesn't need selecting by the user with the mouse in order to type, I want whatever the user types to be input.

I have got as far as making it so that the user only needs to hover their mouse over the widget in order to use it using:

```
co.owner['sys'].layout.input.system.focused_widget = co.owner['sys'].layout.input
co.owner['sys'].layout.input.just_activated = 1
```

I can't however seem to find which attribute needs changing in order for the widget to always think the mouse is hovering over it,

```
co.owner['sys'].layout.input._hover = True
```

doesn't seem to do this.

I've also tried

```
co.owner['sys'].layout.input.activate()
```

but this constantly refreshes the input field so I can't type more than 1 letter.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I think I have managed to solve this by doing the following:</strike>

```
co = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

keyboard = co.sensors["textinputkeyboard"]

    for key,status in keyboard.events:
        if status == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
            co.owner['sys'].layout.input._handle_key(key,False) #text will always be lower case
            if key == bge.events.ENTERKEY: #This is so the enter callback still works
                 co.owner['sys'].layout.on_input_enter(co.owner['sys'].layout.input)
```

The above will work so long as the mouse doesn't make the text input active, in which case every character will be typed twice. In order to avoid this I commented out line 472 of bgui/widget.py:

```
widget._handle_key(key, is_shifted)
```

I realized this is a bit messy, but it works! If anybody has a cleaner way of doing this (I'm certain there is!) hmu.

I found a clean solution to this: 
First, remove the if statement:

```
if self._hover:
```

from the _handle_key() method in bgui/widget.py.

Then include:

```
    co.owner['sys'].layout.input.system.focused_widget = co.owner['sys'].layout.input
```

So that the textinput widget is always focused